# Adding two input boxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add two already calculated and formatted input fields and not having much luck. My code is:

```
<input type='text' id='cage_linear_feet' value='83'>
<input type='text' id='cage_estimate' disabled>
<br>
<input type='text' id='cage_doors' value='3'>
<input type='text' id='doors_estimate' disabled>
<br>
<input type='text' id='cage_totals' disabled>
<script>
   function format(n) {
       return n.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
   }

   //Linear Feet Calculation

      $(document).ready(LinearFeet); 
      document.getElementById('cage_linear_feet').addEventListener("keyup", LinearFeet);

      var inputBox1 = document.getElementById('cage_linear_feet');

      function LinearFeet(){
         document.getElementById('cage_estimate').value = format(inputBox1.value*225);
      }

   //Doors Calculation

      $(document).ready(CageDoors); 
      document.getElementById('cage_doors').addEventListener("keyup", CageDoors);

      var inputBox2 = document.getElementById('cage_doors');

      function CageDoors(){
         document.getElementById('doors_estimate').value = format(inputBox2.value*1800);
      }

</script>
```

How do I add **cage_estimate** and **doors_estimate** together and display in **cage_totals** in real time?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are asking

**how to convert comma separated currency into number in java script**

```
  parseFloat
```

This function calculate total. You have to call it in each key functions.

```
  function setTotal(){
      var x=document.getElementById('doors_estimate').value;
      var y=document.getElementById('cage_estimate').value;

      if(x ){
        if(y){
            var z=(parseFloat(x.replace(',',''))+parseFloat(y.replace(',','')));            
            document.getElementById('cage_totals').value=format(z);
        }
      }
  }
```

calling codes

```
  function LinearFeet(){
    var inputBox1 = document.getElementById('cage_linear_feet');        
     document.getElementById('cage_estimate').value = format(inputBox1.value*225);
     setTotal();
  }


  function CageDoors(){
    var inputBox2 = document.getElementById('cage_doors');      
     document.getElementById('doors_estimate').value = format(inputBox2.value*1800);
     setTotal();
  }
```

Referances:

[parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

[replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. How do I get the cage_totals to show in as a div? E.g. <div id="cage_totals"></div>

Comment: @JohnHiggins document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML=format(z);

Comment: Great, thanks Sanka. Just worked it out but you updated the post before I got to it! Thanks again.